# How can I deduplicate filenames across directories?

Tags: bash, gsutil

I run the following gsutil command:

```
gsutil ls -d gs://mybucket/v${version}/folder1/*/*.whl |
  sort -V |
  grep -e "/*.whl"
```

I get:

```
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560924028/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560926922/file1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560930522/file1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1561568612/file1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1561595893/file1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1561654308/file1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1563319372/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1563319400/file1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1563329633/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1563411368/file1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1565916833/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1565921265/file1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1566258114/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Since some files in different folders have the same names, how can I retrieve unique filenames ignoring the path?

Comment: `unique files regarding the path?` - so which one? Please specify.

Comment: file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl  exists 4 times

Comment: So `file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl` should be in the output or not? Please be specific. I ask - assuming the command returns what you present, which files should be in the output? Should the path be in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
blabla_your_command | rev | sort -t'/' -u -k1,1 | rev
```

`rev` reverses lines. Then I unique sort using `/` as a separator on the first field. After the line is reversed, the first field will be the filename, so sorting -u on it would return only unique filenames. Then the line needs to be reversed back.

The following command:

```
cat <<EOF |
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560924028/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560926922/file1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560930522/file1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1561568612/file1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1561595893/file1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1561654308/file1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1563319372/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1563319400/file1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1563329633/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1563411368/file1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1565916833/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1565921265/file1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1566258114/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
EOF
rev | sort -t'/' -u -k1,1 | rev
```

outputs:

```
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560930522/file1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560926922/file1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1561568612/file1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560924028/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check awk option given below, this will print the last occurrence of delimiter '/', it worked for me

example:
gsutil ls gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560930522 | awk -F/ '{print $(NF)}'

print all the file names under '1560930522'

Comment: Hello, Desikan, and welcome to Stackoverflow!

Please read the question carefully: it asks for a list of _unique_ filenames: a list of filenames with the duplicates removed. Your solution will remove the directory names, but it will not remove duplicates.

Please feel free to edit and resubmit your answer—and thanks for contributing!

- Adam
(Just a guy who's been using Stackoverflow forever)

Answer (score 0):

```
your_command|awk -F/ '!($NF in a){a[$NF]; print}'
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560924028/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560926922/file1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560930522/file1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1561568612/file1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

4 different ways of saying the same thing

> ```
> nawk -F'^.+/' '++_[$NF]<NF'
>
> gawk -F'/' '__[$NF]++<!_'
>
> mawk -F/ '_^__[$NF]++'
>
> mawk2 -F/ '!_[$NF]--'
> ```

```
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560924028/file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560926922/file1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1560930522/file1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
gs://mybucket/v1.0.0/folder1/1561568612/file1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple, straightforward solution:

```
$ your_gsutil_command | xargs -L 1 basename | sort -u
```

The easiest way to remove paths is with `basename`. Unfortunately it accepts only a single filename, which must be on the command line (not from `stdin`), so we need to take the following steps:

1. Create the list of files.
   We do this with `your_gsutil_command`, but you can use any command that generates a list of files.
2. Send each one to `basename` to remove its path.
   The `xargs` command does this for us by reading its `stdin` and invoking `basename` repeatedly, passing the data as command-line arguments. But `xargs` efficiently tries to reduce the number of invocations by passing multiple filenames on each command line, and that breaks `basename`. We prevent that with `-L 1`, limiting it to only one line (that is, one filename) at a time.
3. Remove duplicates.
   The `sort -u` command does this.

Using your example data:

```
$ gsutil ls -d gs://mybucket/v${version}/folder1/*/*.whl |
  xargs -L 1 basename | sort -u

file1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
file1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
file1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
file1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

---

**Caveat:** Spaces break everything.

So far we've assumed the filenames and folders do not contain spaces. Spaces break `basename` because needs exactly one filename, and it would interpret spaces as separators between multiple filenames. We can get around this in two ways:

**`ls -Q`:** If you're deduplicating *local* filenames, you can use the (non-`gsutil`) `ls` command with the `-Q` flag to put the filenames in quotes, so `basename` will interpret spaces as part of the filenames rather than separators.

**`gsutil`:** The `-Q` flag is unfortunately not supported, so we'll need to escape the spaces manually:

```
$ your_gsutil_command | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs -L 1 basename | sort -u
```

Here we use the `sed` command to escape each space by inserting a backslash before it. (That is, we replace   with `\` . Note that we *also* need to escape the backslash in the `sed` command, which is why we use `\\` and not just `\`.)